# How can i install custom third party library in IBM Cloud functions action custom package?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I would like to use **LanguageTranslatorV3** and **ToneAnalyzerV3** python 
library in IBM Cloud function custom serverless action.

I created one sample Action in IBM Cloud function and try to import the above packages, but It gives me module error.

So, How can I install the above modules in my custom action?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That process of integrating third party libraries is described in the IBM Cloud Functions documentation as part of [preparing apps for actions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-prep#prep_python). For Python you could use zip to package the environment, either with or without using virtualenv. Another option for even more complex environments could be to use a Docker image.

The function in this [tutorial-related repo](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats/tree/master/functions) uses the zip-approach.

Many packages are already available in the [standard Python runtime environments](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-runtimes#python-packages). Be sure to specify the right runtime version when creating the action.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I added some more. Regarding ibm_waton, try watson-developer-cloud which is the older name. It may not have been updated in the runtime env.

Comment: Yes, `from watson_developer_cloud import LanguageTranslatorV3` worked. Thank you very much for your reply. You saved my day. :)

Answer (score 1):

For python, there is a detailed tutorial about how to use custom packages on OpenWhisk(IBM Cloud Functions use this project): http://jamesthom.as/blog/2017/04/27/python-packages-in-openwhisk/, the section `Installing Packages With Docker` and `Speeding Up Deployments` make it even better

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Python runtime](https://github.com/ibm-functions/runtime-python) for IBM Cloud Functions does already include the `watson-developer-cloud` [package](https://pypi.org/project/watson-developer-cloud/).

You should be able to use that without manually bundling the packages.

Comment: Yes, You may right but when I tried to use `from ibm_watson import LanguageTranslatorV3 ` in python 3.7 runtime environment then It gives me the error that **ibm_watson** module not found. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `from watson_developer_cloud import LanguageTranslatorV3` worked. Thank you very much the answer